# How to set maximum resolution with MediaCapture in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I was working on windows phone 8.1(RT) I used the MediaCapture to take a photo(Do keep in mind not interested in previewing the pic to be taken).
I used the following code but the quality of the picture is terrible only the part which illuminates light is seen in the picture taken.

```
private static async Task<DeviceInformation> GetCameraID(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel desiredCamera)
{
    // get available devices for capturing pictures
    DeviceInformation deviceID = (await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture))
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.EnclosureLocation != null && x.EnclosureLocation.Panel == desiredCamera);

    if (deviceID != null) return deviceID;
    else throw new Exception(string.Format("Camera of type {0} doesn't exist.", desiredCamera));
}

public async Task takeAPicture()
{
    var cameraID = await GetCameraID(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);
    captureManager = new MediaCapture();

    await captureManager.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
    {
        StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
        PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview,
        AudioDeviceId = string.Empty,
        VideoDeviceId = cameraID.Id
    });

    var maxResolution = captureManager.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo).Aggregate((i1, i2) => (i1 as VideoEncodingProperties).Width > (i2 as VideoEncodingProperties).Width ? i1 : i2);
    await captureManager.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.Photo, maxResolution);

    StorageFile photoFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("myFirstPhoto.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
    //take a photo with choosen Encoding

    await captureManager.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), photoFile);
    captureManager.Dispose();
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: As I've played with this on my phone once, it turned out that the biggest width doesn't mean the biggest resolution. Why not to enumarate available widths/heights and choose the combination which will give the largest multiplication result (width*height)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you configuring your MediaCapture to give you "preview-quality" photos. Do this instead:

```
await captureManager.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
{
    StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
    PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.Photo, // I believe your bug was here
    AudioDeviceId = string.Empty,
    VideoDeviceId = cameraID.Id
});
```

Or really, just try the defaults for most of those properties, and only set the VideoDeviceId to choose a camera. It should help in narrowing down the issue.

As for setting a higher photo capture resolution, something like this might work:

```
private async Task SetPhotoResolution()
{
    var resolutions = _captureManager.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo).Select(x => x as VideoEncodingProperties);

    var maxRes = resolutions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Height * x.Width).FirstOrDefault();

    await _captureManager.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.Photo, maxRes);
}
```

Do make sure that the aspect ratio of the photo resolution matches the aspect ratio of the preview resolution, or you might get some banding near the edges on some phones.

Also, the phone I tested this on only returned NV12 `VideoEncodingProperties` for the `GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties` call on the `MediaStreamType.Photo` stream. You may need to handle an enumerable that also contains ImageEncodingProperties as well, on a different device.

Comment: tried the code but couldnt get any reference of PhotoEncodingProperties or anything similar tried it with VideoEncoding properties with the changes you suggested but the photo just has a dark image with a white band.Can't see anything

Comment: Sorry, it appears my edit wasn't picked up in time before you checked the answer. It should show up soon. What phone are you running this on? Any chance you can upload an example picture to imgur.com? Have you tried a different camera on the device (front vs. back)?

Comment: I'm using a lumia 730 and tried with both the cameras(Front and back) when i add PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.Photo I get a black screen with a white band else I get a dark resolution photo when i use a VideoPreview. I have uploaded the code [here](https://5sg8zg.bl3302.livefilestore.com/y2mQ1_6JzGDpaXTXThMaQCloTNWQGae1ql3vhe2u5ZBi5k19FRap4bqyCJKte0mSyxBd3ttWwWsURGH6X8vDkhMvIxnxJG6PfCZf3h7lj9GBJjsJeh6kPW1-1wWTc-fjBUtsKrJTwbjkFYia3lpShd5hA/CameraCapture.zip?download&psid=1) the commented lines in the method takePicBtn_Click are your suggested answer.

Comment: I'd love to help, but I can't access the code you posted.

Comment: sorry about the [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/81907255/CameraCapture.zip) it is.

Comment: I can't test it at the moment since I'm away, so I'll give it a try next week. I tried skimming through the code, and what's jumping at me is that in the version you sent me, the preview isn't started. You need to run the preview so that automatic exposure kicks in. If you just commented it out for a bit and it's not the source of the problem, I'll investigate further on Wednesday or so and get back to you. In the meantime, try to copy as much as you can from this Win10 sample: http://aka.ms/2015builduniversalcamerasample. Almost everything there applies to Win8 too.

Comment: Oh yeah cause I didn't want the preview based on the requirements.But I could always add it and hide it. I'll try doing that and see if the result is any better. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Thanks for the link I figured it out since I wasnt using a preview the resolution was bad now I'm able to get good resolution images. Thanks a lot again.